# QRegEx help, RegEx in general

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I'm in the process of attempting to learn RegEx. I've been tasked with generating a QPixmap out of several hundred *.png files. Ideally, it would be a PixMap matrix.

I think that QRegEx is the best way to perform this action so I can insert the pixmaps into a matrix without having to sort.

My pattern I'm trying to match:

```
runner_(int)_(int).png
```

Where the first integer has bounds [-1, 13] and the second [00, 20]. There is a leading zero on the second integer.

This is my code attempt:

```
    // find the png files in the thing
    QDir fileDir(iconPath);        
    QFileInfoList fileList = fileDir.entryInfoList();

    QRegExp rxlen("runner_([^\\_]{1,1}])_([^\\_]{1,1}]).png");        
    foreach (const QFileInfo &info, fileList) {
        qDebug() << info.fileName();
        int pos = rxlen.indexIn(info.fileName());
        if (pos > 1) {
            qDebug() << rxlen.cap(1);
            qDebug() << rxlen.cap(2);
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Didn't find any";
        }
    }
```

My question: Please help with the RegEx expression.

Please be gentle, I'm new to RegEx (started learning it about an hour ago!)

Thanks :)

Comment: There is no real question in that post...

Comment: How do you figure? It's quite clear I need help with the RegEx expression, otherwise it wouldn't be tagged as such.

Comment: How about adding "What's the best regex to use in this scenario" or something.  I was reading it and having to guess at what you really wanted...  Help with the code?  Help with the regex?  You didn't show whether you tried what you wrote and it did or didn't work.  IE, you can't tell what the problem is by reading it.

Comment: Ah point taken. Now that I read it again, it does seem a bit ambiguous.Edited appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{1,1}` is absolutely useless, means something that's used between 1 and 1 times, ie once. You can just write the element in the string.

Since you already have your pattern down all nice and proper, you can just build the regex straight from it:

```
runner_(-1|[0-9]|0+[0-9]|0*1[0123])_([0-9]|0+[0-9]|0*1[0-9]|20)\.png
```

Basically just writing patterns for all numbers in your range.

Edited to escape the dot.
Edited again to allow leading zeroes.

Comment: As an aside, you were pretty close if you didn't really care about the fact that they are integers, and whether or not their ranges matter, if you replace `{1,1}` in your post with `+` it will work (it will just spit out a lot of false positives too).

Comment: I am not able to get it to match. I copied and pasted your answer into my QRegExp, no matches.

Perhaps it's my indexing? Second integer is [00,20] not [0,20]

Comment: Actually Blindy, this worked, except I had to take off the "runner_" and the ".png" bits. I'm accepting this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe it was an issue of case sensitivity? You should turn it off for file matching. Always prefer full regular expressions when possible, with anchors and everything.